# How to set wp_editor to be email friendly?

Tags: options, wp-editor, html-editor, html-email

I am sending emails via `wp_mail()` using a text/html header. So i need html formatted content.

I want to use `wp_editor()` to edit my custom email template options. It has a **Visual** and **Text** tab for viewing. If I write html using the **Text** tab, then click **Visual**. It looks great! I can see the preview! buuuuuut sadly it also removes my html and replaces it with some other format..

I noticed there are options with wp_editor. Is there any that are completely html friendly?

Comment: To write Emails properly (and probably way better), you can use Litmus editor. it's free and web based and have panel for preview and helpful with responsive emails . Wordprerss TinyMCE or Gutenberg may add some html tags itself, to remove that you may have to modify the plugin

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will give Litmus a try